# Navigate to a specific directory of a PC in the network (with credential)

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-access, shared-folders

I need to retrieve files and folders from my coworker's PC (who is at vacation at the moment). He emailed me his IP Address, a username and password to access his files. He also instructed the location of the files on his PC is at: `C:/orant/shared/...`

I managed to access his PC via my PC (by the way both OS are Windows 7). My problem is that when I try to access his PC I can only see two folders, nothing more. It seems that he haven't shared his drive *(but he told me on email otherwise)*.

I have attempt to navigate to the following directory: `\\192.XXX.XXX.XXX\C:\orant\shared`, though I know more or less it won't work.

My question is how can I navigate to that specified directory?

> *If all else fail, I can always go to his PC's location physically: we're only a building apart.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect via the C$ share if he hasn't shared out a specific folder. So you would connect to \IPAddress\C$ then you will be prompted for credentials. Which you will want to append either the target computer name on the front of or the ip. So the username will look like 192.168.1.1\someguy.

Comment: Errr.... now when I try to access the PC via `\\192.X.X.X\C$` and use the same credential, it return an _Access Is denied._ message.

Comment: To access a share you have to have rights. In this case admin rights.

Comment: But he said that the given account has Administrative rights... or should I log using the account "Administrator"?

Comment: If you know the computer name, you can try that as well. It is possible the IP address changed on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently learned that Windows user can use the Remote Desktop Connection program as an alternative. You must first enabled the remote connection of that PC first though. To do that use the following to navigate (on Windows 7):

1. Open <kbd>My Computer</kbd>
2. Click the <kbd>System Properties</kbd> tab on the menu. A new page will  appear.
3. Choose the <kbd>System Protection</kbd> option found on the left side. A modal window will appear.
4. Go to the last tab, the <kbd>Remote</kbd> tab.
5. Tick either one of these radio buttons found at the lower part of that tab:

   - Allow connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop (less secure)
   - Allow connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication (more secure)
6. Click the  <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

After enabling this feature on the target PC, you can run the program `mstsc.exe` / [Remote Desktop Connection](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ph/windows/connect-using-remote-desktop-connection#connect-using-remote-desktop-connection=windows-7) on your PC to connect using the given credentials. Easy transfer of files from PC to PC is one of the many features of this program.